# Parse to datetime from string years

Tags: c#

how to convert `string` year to `DateTime` format ?

my code :

```
// click button
string a = "2014";
DateTime b = DateTime.Parse(a);
MessageBox.Show(b.ToString());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  can try something like  this

```
var year = int.Parse("2014");   
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
Console.WriteLine(dateTime.ToString());
```

Comment: error message 

`Additional information: Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.`

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: thank for solution @BRAHIM Kamel